# Apache NiFi JSON to SQL with pre processing

Tags: oracle, apache-nifi

I am completely new NiFi but I understand from people it is good.

However, I am going to be sent a JSON, where there be an embedded array which can contain hex, byte, an ASCII characters. These values will nee converting to string values before inserting into Oracle.

Searching the internet, there are no proper examples to follow which converts JSON to SQL and converts data from hex to string, etc. Are there any examples to follow? Has anyone done something similar and advise?

Comment: We handled operations like that by inserting the raw JSON into a CLOB column and then using a combination of views, PL/SQL packages and a trigger to parse the individual rows into the actual data tables. it was much more efficient to handle data operations there (especially if they can be done in bulk rather than one at a time) than it was to do it in a NiFi processor.

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways as I know of to convert JSON to SQL:

The first one is by using Jolt Transformation, which is not very efficient with large data comparatively.

The second one is which I prefer by using a series of processors to convert JSON to SQL: EvaluateJsonPath --> AttributesToJson --> ConvertJSONToSQL -->PutSQL.

There is a processor known as EncodeContent or EncodeAttribute for the conversion of hex to different formats.

[image]